# How to fix issue with StAX parsing in java using xml?

Tags: java, xml, stax

I am trying to parse the value `displayName` from an xml file I have. I am using the `StAX` way to do the parsing, however when I go to parse the code it grabs everything but the actual value I want. I honestly have no clue why because I strictly mention to grab the name that `.equalsIgnoreCase()`. I don't receive any errors, the only problem is I can't grab the value that I need.

**Java:**

```
import java.io.File;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Iterator;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLEventReader;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException;
import javax.xml.stream.events.*;

public class Driver {

    private static boolean bname;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, XMLStreamException {

        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Robert\\Desktop\\root\\SDKCode\\src\\main\\java\\com\\example\\xmlClass\\data.xml");


        parser(file);
    }

    public static void parser(File file) throws FileNotFoundException, XMLStreamException {

        bname = false;


        XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();


        XMLEventReader eventReader = factory.createXMLEventReader(new FileReader(file));


        while (eventReader.hasNext()) {

            XMLEvent event = eventReader.nextEvent();

            // This will trigger when the tag is of type <...>
            if (event.isStartElement()) {
                StartElement element = (StartElement) event;


                Iterator<Attribute> iterator = element.getAttributes();
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    Attribute attribute = iterator.next();
                    QName name = attribute.getName();
                    String value = attribute.getValue();
                    System.out.println(name + " = " + value);
                }


                if (element.getName().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("displayName")) {
                    bname = true;
                }

            }


            if (event.isEndElement()) {
                EndElement element = (EndElement) event;


                if (element.getName().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("displayName")) {
                    bname = false;
                }


            }


            if (event.isCharacters()) {
                // Depending upon the tag opened the data is retrieved .
                Characters element = (Characters) event;

                if (bname) {
                    System.out.println(element.getData());
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<results
        xmlns="urn:www-collation-com:1.0"
        xmlns:coll="urn:www-collation-com:1.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="urn:www-collation-com:1.0
              urn:www-collation-com:1.0/results.xsd">

    <WebServiceImpl array="1"
        guid="FFVVRJ5618KJRHNFUIRV845NRUVHR" xsi:type="coll:com.model.topology.app.web.WebService">
        <isPlaceholder>false</isPlaceholder>
        <displayName>server.servername.siqom.siqom.us.com</displayName>
        <hierarchyType>WebService</hierarchyType>
        <hierarchyDomain>app.web</hierarchyDomain>
    </WebServiceImpl>
</results>
```

Comment: What if you would debug? What does `element.getName().toString()` return? I suspect it returns something having a special namespace. Try `element.getName().getLocalPart().equalsIgnoreCase("displayName")`

Comment: @AxelRichter Thank you, after running the debug, I found that it was not returning anything. So there was nothing to match it. However, when I added your code it works.